# Unity 2D game, big tiles

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d

I am making a big open world game where the map is hand drawn.

The dimensions of the map are 12800x3840.

Thus I have made world-tiles 1280x768 ( having 20x12 64x64 tiles )

My initial approach is to draw 9 world-tiles which are around the player. I also want my collision system to work on a tile based approach where i have a 20x12 2 dimension array. Is this the right way?

How do I do this in Unity? What objects do I use?

Comment: Just going to say straight away this question is to broad so you may want to show what you have tried so far, but the best answer I have for you is just take a look at https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/2d-roguelike-tutorial that will help get you started

Comment: What I am doing right now is I have a World GameObject which is totally empty. On start it checks the coordinates of the player, calculates which 9 tiles have to be created. It creates them and adds them to the World GameObjects. I then create the player and add him to the World, and center the camera on him.

Comment: If creating a grid of 20x12 blocks which are 64x64 each is working for you, I would say go for it. For me the best practice is to try and see when it comes down to coding. There isn't always a right or wrong way, it really does depend on your end goals and problems.

Answer (score 0):

I used X-UniTMX to very good results on a tile based strategy game I'm working on. First you create the map using Tiled then you can import it using this software.

Tiled:
http://www.mapeditor.org

X-UniTMX:
https://bitbucket.org/Chaoseiro/x-unitmx/wiki/Home